# Is there (inexpensive) software to optimize the assignment of office rooms?

Tags: windows, open-source, web-apps

I have 20 private offices in my building and 30 employees. Each employee works only part time and needs a private office during working hours. I need to minimize employees shifting around between offices. Also, employees are on a regular, weekly schedule. However, that weekly employee schedule changes every six months or so.

At present, office assignments are worked out on a trial and error basis. I’d prefer a software solution. Any advice?

Comment: How is your trial and error conducted right now? If you have a mature excel spreadsheet to handle the task, maybe it could suffice to use some python script to do the trial and error for you.

Comment: No mature Excel doc I’m afraid. I inherited the doc. It originally came together organically, when there were fewer employees and when their office hours were more uniform (ie everyone 9-5, no part timers). Excel is used for layout currently, not calculation.

Comment: Found anything yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try out the suggestions in the answer?

Comment: I think you can solve this with the Excel Solver Plugin, or the LibreOffice Solver. You can google for tutorials where someone optimizes student-to-classroom allocation  with constraints (e.g, "allocate twins always into different classes"). This would get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of free constraint solvers, which you can look at:

- [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/)
- [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/)

The main issue is to be able to choose the right model. So I suggest having a look at the documentation first, available on the links.

In terms of displaying the the room availability in a calendar and choosing what is available, I suggest an open source solution like [Booked](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpscheduleit).